# Bootstrap CSS apply active class based on another div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to apply the *active* class to a button only when another div's columns are 3.

The following example illustrates what I mean:

```
<div>
   <button class="active">3 col</button>
   <button class="">4 col</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-12">
...
</div>
```

As you can see, I would like the "3 col" button be active when the screen is *md* and the "4 col" one when the screen is *lg*.

Can I achieve this only with **CSS**?.

Comment: You cannot add or remove classes using only CSS.

Comment: Isn't something like **active-md**, **active-lg**, based on media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to add two different classes, such as `active-3col` and `active-4col`.

```
<div>
   <button class="active-3col">3 col</button>
   <button class="active-4col">4 col</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-12">
...
</div>
```

Then, in CSS you can use the Bootstrap breakpoints to style them accordingly.
*md* is `min-width: 768px`.
*lg* is `min-width: 992px`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .active-3col {

  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .active-4col {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, I just answered by asking for something like this on your previous comment. +1.

Comment: Cool. Sorry, I made a mistake. It is not possible to start a class with a number. I edited the code.